# Difference of magnitude of two vectors $\leq$ sum of vector magnitudes

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, cauchy-problem

I try to find out why this relationship holds:

> $$‖\vec x -\vec y ‖ ≤ ‖\vec x ‖ + ‖\vec y ‖$$

Comment: this is just the triangle inequality. $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$. set $a=x$ and $b=-y$

Comment: And triangle inequality always holds for 3 non-collinear points or 2 non-collinear vectors.